# pgfplots + gnuplot: why does setting clip = false in axis options completely ruin graphs of implicit functions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = 0,
xmax = 1.5,
ymin = 0,
ymax = 6.2831853072,
ytick={0,0.7853981634,1.5707963268,2.3561944902,3.1415926536,3.926990817,4.7123889804,5.4977871438,6.2831853073}, yticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{4}$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\frac{3\pi}{4}$,$\pi$,$\frac{5\pi}{4}$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$\frac{7\pi}{4}$,$2\pi$},
grid=major,
xlabel=$\gamma$,
ylabel=$\phi$]

\addplot +[no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
blue,
] gnuplot {
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
    unset surface;
    set view map;
    set isosamples 500;
    splot x*cos(y)-1;
};

\addplot +[no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
blue,
] gnuplot {
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
    unset surface;
    set view map;
    set isosamples 500;
    splot sin(y);
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Its output is nice:

[image]

Here's the output with `clip = false` set.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[clip = false, xmin = 0,
xmax = 1.5,
ymin = 0, ...
```

[image]

A page full of blue lines! If you look carefully at the bottom, you'll be able to see the long page number.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CW from the comment by Jake, confirmed as solution by the OP (and cleaned up):

The default domain for `x` and `y` in `gnuplot` is `-10:10`. If you want to set `clip=false`, you should restrict the domain in the `\addplot` command: `splot [0:1.5] [0:2*pi] x*cos(y)-1;`.